# Wordpress Buddypress always show members list of group

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, members

I'm working on a Wordpress/Buddypress project and I would like to make the members list of group always visible whether or not the group is private and the logged member belong to the group.

I was thinking I had to change access and visibility of the nav items so I did that:

```
function change_access_group_nav_tabs() {
    if(bp_is_group()) {
        buddypress()->groups->nav->edit_nav( array('visibility' => 'public'), 'members', bp_current_item() );
        buddypress()->groups->nav->edit_nav( array('access' => 'anyone'), 'members', bp_current_item() );
    }
}
add_action( 'bp_actions', 'change_access_group_nav_tabs' );
```

But it didn't work…

Any suggestion how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, I'am quite not completely satisfied but...

First of all, disable members list on group:

```
function change_access_group_nav_tabs() {
    if(bp_is_group()) {
buddypress()->groups->nav->edit_nav( array( 'user_has_access' => false ), 'members', bp_current_item() );
    }
}
add_action( 'bp_actions', 'change_access_group_nav_tabs' );`
```

(btw, setting the value to true actually make the the nav items always here, but we still can't access the group list on click)

And then I simply add a custom BP Group Extension to make my own members list:

```
    class Group_Extension_List_Members extends BP_Group_Extension {
      function __construct() {
        $args = array(
          'slug' => 'members-list',
          'name' => 'Membres',
          'access' => array( 'anyone'),
          'show_tab' => array( 'anyone'),
          'nav_item_position' => 12,
          'screens' => array(
            'create' => array(
              'enabled' => false
            ),
            'edit' => array(
              'enabled' => false
            ),
          )
        );
        parent::init( $args );
      }
      function display( $group_id = NULL ) {
        //Remove user who do not belong to the group on members loop
        function filter_for_groups( $members_template_has_members, $members_template, $r ) {
          for ($i=sizeof($members_template->members)-1; $i >= 0 ; $i--) {
            $user_id = $members_template->members[$i]->id;
            if(!groups_is_user_member( $user_id, bp_get_group_id() )){
              $members_template->member_count = $members_template->member_count-1;
              array_splice($members_template->members, $i, 1);
            }
          }
          if ($members_template->member_count <= 0) {
            return '';
          } else {
            return $members_template_has_members;
          }
        };
        add_filter( 'bp_has_members', 'filter_for_groups', 10, 3 );

        require('/Your/theme/custom/members/loop/members-loop.php');
      }
    }
    bp_register_group_extension( 'Group_Extension_List_Members' );
```

Hope it will help other in the future, And I'm still open to know the good way to proceed.